# What happens if you put rings with the mass of several suns around a black hole?

Tags: the-sun, black-hole, rings

Can someone also explain to me what happens from 7:24 to 9:20 (basically he creates a sun, locks it in place, the sun starts absorbing the black holes' rings and growing, it starts dropping pieces of itself forming another ring and then explodes).

Also why doesn't the black hole absorb the rings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simulation program set up to run outside all sensible and appropriate bounds - to go at that speed the iterations just don't work.  The mathematics is not realistic here.

So what you are seeing is some fun graphics, no more no less.